# How to check whether the key number is repeated in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

How to get the repeated number from the key(b) my program is like this a user enter 166456 and key = 6 then the output must be like 6 is repeated 3 times in the array please also show me if this can be done without array
I am even getting error for int cannot be to int[]

```
    int []a,i,j,count=0,b=0,n;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=sc.nextInt(System.in);
    int []a=new int[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        a[i]=sc.nextInt();

    }
    System.out.println("Which nuber would you like to find:");
    b=sc.nextInt();
    for(j=0;j<n;++j)
    {
        if(a[i]==b)
        {
            ++count;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not found");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No of time "+b+" is repeated "+count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some wrong variable declaration. If you declare an array as `int []a` then it will consider all variables as an array. That's why you are getting the error. Either you can declare as an `int a[]` or declare other variables on a different line.

Please refer below code,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int []a;
        int b=0, count=0;
        int i, j, n;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=sc.nextInt();
        a=new int[n];
        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();

        }
        System.out.println("Which nuber would you like to find:");
        b=sc.nextInt();
        for(j=0;j<n;++j)
        {
            if(a[j]==b)
            {
                ++count;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not found");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No of time "+b+" is repeated "+count);

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
6
1
6
6
4
5
6
Which nuber would you like to find:
6
Not found
Not found
Not found
No of time 6 is repeated 3
```

Comment: still i am not getting the count of the repeated number

Comment: @Ragnarok I am able to see the output. I have updated my answer with output. Please check.

Comment: why its shows Not found as 6 is present in the array??

Comment: @Ragnarok It is because you are printing the value in each iteration. If the value is 6 then it will increment count else it will print not found. If you don't want to display then, remove else block.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood the requirement, You need help regarding finding out the total frequency of the digit from the user's input. (Assuming digits will be only from 0 to 9. Correct me If I am wrong on this assumption).

So, for this, we can just use the integer array of size 10 to store each digit's frequency.  For example, consider the input of total 6 digits - "166456". Our integer array's value will be (from index 0 to 9) 0100113000. So, we can directly return the index of the digit we want to search, in this example return value of array[6] which is 3.

```
    int[] num=new int[10]; // storing each digit's frequency
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt(); // count for total digits
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int index = sc.nextInt();
        num[index]++;
    }
    System.out.println("Which number you would like to find out?");
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    if(num[b]!=0)
        System.out.println("No. of time "+b+" is repeated "+num[b]);
    else
        System.out.println("Not found");
```

Comment: its giving me error and it doesnt retrive the number want any limit or even i dont want to store it in array just find the number of repeated element using the key

Comment: Well, I just run it and it showing output. I am not sure why you are getting an error. We can also use HashMap<Integer, Integer> here. That can help you too.

Comment: Hi  can it be done which out an array like if user enter direct number rather then selecting the storage like in above the array is storing the number if user enters directly 16648 and the key value as 6 it must get 2 times directly as its repeating coutn

Comment: So, Based on your requirement if you want to consider 16648 as a one integer number and by providing the key value as 6, you want the output as 2, then you can do either converting number into string and then find occurrences of the key digit in whole string or you can extract each digit by divide and modulo by 10.